# Сбрасывыется значение переменной python

Tags: python

Имеется код:

```
from tkinter import Tk
root=Tk()

code = ""

def key_pressed(event, code=code):
    code += event.char
    print(code)

root.bind("<Key>",key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

То есть при нажатии на любую клавишу, символ добавляется в переменную `code`. Но при тесте программы вижу, что при нажатии на клавишу у меня значение переменной `code` становится пустым и в него записывается только последняя клавиша. Кто знает, подскажите в чем проблема?

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import Tk
root=Tk()

code = ""
def key_pressed(event):
    global code
    code += event.char
    print(code)

def osh():
    print("Press F10")

root.bind("<F10>", osh())
root.bind("<Key>",key_pressed)

root.mainloop()
```

При запуске выводит "Press F10", хотя должен выводить только если нажал F10. Что делать?

[image: Ошибка такая]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При изменении значения внутри функции создается локальная переменная `code`, которая скрывает глобальную. Это приводит к тому, что внутри функции `key_pressed` используется локальная переменная `code`. которая инициализируется пустой строкой каждый раз при вызове функции.

**Updated(Решение проблемы):**

```
def key_pressed(event):
    global code
    code += event.char
    print(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [атрибут функции](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/opredelenie-funktsij-python/funktsii-mogut-imet-atributy/) для накопления последовательности символов.

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
def key_pressed(event):
    key_pressed.sequence += event.char
    print(key_pressed.sequence)


key_pressed.sequence = ''
root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

```
1
12
123
123a
123ab
123abc
123abcd
123abcde
123abcdef
```